# If $A=(i\cdot j)_{n\times n}$ and $B=(\min(i,j))_{n\times n}$, calculate $AB=(c_{ij})_{n\times n}$

Tags: matrices

If $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$, $a_{ij}=i\cdot j$ and

$B=(b_{ij})_{n\times n}$, $b_{ij}=\min(i,j)$.

How calculate a formula for $c_{ij}$, with $C=(c_{ij})_{n\times n}=AB$.

For example:

$n=2:$

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}
3&5\\
6&10\end{pmatrix}$$

$n=3:$

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}
  6&    11&    14\\
    12&    22&    28\\
    18 &   33 &   42\end{pmatrix}$$

$n=4:$

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}
10 &   19 &   26 &   30\\
    20 &   38 &   52 &   60\\
    30 &   57 &   78 &   90\\
    40 &   76 &  104 &  120\end{pmatrix}$$

$n=5:$

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}
15   & 29&    41 &   50 &   55\\
    30  &  58 &   82 &  100 &  110\\
    45 &   87 &  123&   150 &  165\\
    60  & 116 &  164 &  200 &  220\\
    75  & 145 &  205 &  250 &  275\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that $c_{ij}=i\cdot c_{1j}$. Is there a formula for the first row $c_{1j}$?

Any hint woul be appreciated.

Comment: $c_{ik}=\sum_jij \min(j,k)=i\sum_jj \min(j,k)$ then break the sum into parts for $j<k$ and $j\ge k$

Comment: @BenjaminWang Thanks but Is there a formula without using the minimum function or by cases?

Comment: After analysing the cases you will have a cubic formula which won't involve cases. Alternatively you can look directly for patterns: Looking at the first row of $n=5$, the differences are $14,12,9,5$, and their differences are $2,3,4$ (consecutive integers). So there should be a cubic that you can fit.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Thanks for your solution!